# search an XML file and return the string that contains the search

Tags: android, xml, string, search

I have a `strings.xml` file with 52 strings (week1 - week52). Every week contains a poam. I want to be able to search the `strings.xml` and return the relevant poam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that:

```
<string name="week0">Poam 0</string>
<string name="week1">Poam 1</string>
<string name="week2">Poam 2</string>    

int weekOfYear = new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
String poamOfWeek = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("week" + String.valueOf(weekOfYear), "string", getPackageName()));
```